# Heroku, like a git repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I am having a problem wrapping my brain around Heroku.  I created a small ruby on rails app, got it deployed to the free version of heroku and used a lot of git calls to do so.  I have to say, can heroku be used as like a bitbucket as well as a host for code?  Or is there a good doc out there that shows how to work with git repos and heroku both.  I am newish to git so perhaps im just not getting the flow.  I know I have a local commit I can do but then I can push and pull from a repo (and i was doing this to get heroku working) is that my repo or should I push and pull to like bit bucket and then get my branches/merges working and then for a production push goto heroku?

whats the typical work flow with heroku I guess I am asking, it isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about *typical*, but for me, I've added the heroku destination as a remote according to [their instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) and just push to it, while keeping my development repository on github, bitbucket, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

> can heroku be used as like a bitbucket as well as a host for code?

Yes, all git repos are just git repos so when you do a git push, there is a full copy of all history at that location. Because of this try pushing from one git repo and then cloning to another.

You can do anything with the heroku remote that you can do with any git remote.  Try pushing a branch to heroku.

```
git co -b branch; git push heroku branch;
```

After that heroku will have a full git branch.

I recommend you check out the awesomeness of a decentralized VCS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control